# Sublime Text: Change default python.dll file

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

When I try to run some Python code (which works in Anaconda Spyder) in Sublime Text, I get this error:

```
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 15:00:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "pandas\src\numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas\hashtable.c:38262)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_internal.py", line 14, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: Module use of python33.dll conflicts with this version of Python.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: Module use of python33.dll conflicts with this version of Python. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Although the SublimeREPL is Python 3.5.1, the program seems to be using `python33.dll`. It seems like it should be using `python35.dll`.

In `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text`, I see `python33.dll`. So, I place it in a temp folder and put `python35.dll` (from the Anaconda folder) there instead. I restart Sublime Text.

Then, the program doesn't open, saying `python33.dll` is missing. This makes me think that there's some setting file in Sublime Text that's looking for `python33.dll` specifically, and it won't accept `python35.dll`.

I went through Sublime's PackageResourceViewer and couldn't find anything within the Python package that indicated a `python33.dll` preference. For reference, my PYTHONPATH points to C:\Anaconda3\ which is where my Python installation lies.

Is there any easy way to switch out `python33.dll` with `python35.dll` in `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text`?

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, you should not do this. Python 3.3.3 is compiled into the Sublime Text 3 binary and is used to run the Python API and plugin system, among other things. Inserting a Python 3.5 `.dll` will cause all sorts of conflicts between the ABI and the compiled-in bits, killing the program.

So, instead of fiddling around with that, please edit your question and post the code you were trying to run along with *detailed information* on exactly how you were trying to run it, and we can troubleshoot that instead.